# Chrome doesn't allow scroll using jQuery .height

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome

I'm using jQuery to make a div the size of the window (-175px) and resize when the window is resized. The window stops resizing if the div gets to it's min-height of 600px.

```
$("#error-container").height($(window).height() - 175);
  $(window).resize(function () {
    $("#error-container").height($(window).height() - 175)
  });
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#error-container").css("min-height", "600px")
  });
```

This works, however on chrome there seems to be a strange bug where you cannot scroll down to see the footer once the window becomes too small vertically. See the screen shots:

[image: Chrome]

On chrome, it's cutting the content off but doesn't allow me to scroll to see the remaining content below.

[image: Firefox]

In firefox it behaves correctly and allows me to scroll down and see the rest of the content.

It also works as it should in Safari in iOS and on Mac OSX.

Does anyone know what could be causing it?

I've tried adding `overflow: scroll;` to the parent div, but that doesn't work.

Comment: You are cutting part of element setting its height: `$("#error-container").height($(window).height() - 175)`, aren't you?

Comment: @Regent That's simply setting it's height to 175px less than the height of the browser window. The div with 'reg charity number' is a seperate div as well, which isn't floated or removed from the DOM so it should always be scrollable to?

Comment: I have created [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Regent3000/Lqgxjuqg/). Is it correct situation or not?

Comment: No Sorry, the content is being hidden when you resize your browser window to about 500px high, it then doesn't let me scroll to see the footer in chrome, but it does in FF and Safari. @Regent